# Unable to install Xuni.CollectionView using NuGet in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

while installing Xuni.CollectionView using Nuget of portable option of Project it showing the error below:

```
"Could not install package 'Xuni.CollectionView 2.1.20161.86'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install this package without any problems in my Xamarin.Forms Shared Project -> Add Packages... in a specific iOS or Android project search for the package and install it, see image attached:

[image]